Is $\mathbb R/\mathbb N$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z?$
Where $\mathbb R/\mathbb N$ is the quotient topological space, where $\mathbb N$ is collapsed onto a point. Same with $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z.$
I was thinking I could prove it wasn't homeomorphic using connectedness. Help would be much appreciated.

There is a point in $\mathbb R/\mathbb N$ that is not a point in a simple loop, while no such point exists in $\mathbb R/\mathbb N.$ So they cannot be homeomorphic.

Your idea to use connectedness can also be made to work. Try to work out what the cut points are of each space..

I like @IzaakvanDongen ‘s way of doing this, because it makes use of the essential pictorial difference between the two:  one is an infinite bouquet of circles, the other is same except it has a stem.
